# Changing the name of php5-fpm pool causes 502

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a webserver running multiple sites, each site has it's own php5-fpm pool.

One particular site is behaving very strangely. I have a conf file setup for it in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/ and everything is the same as all the other sites on the server, except for one thing...

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can we used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[www]
```

The FastCGI address is:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm/website.sock
```

and that matches the fastcgi_pass rule in the vhost conf file:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/website.sock;
```

I've narrowed it down to the pool name, if I change [www] to anything else, and restart php5-fpm, I get 502 across all sites.

It's very bizarre that doing the same process on any other site on the server doesn't cause this issue. Each site is happily running on it's own pool, except for this one.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by doing the following:

1. `sudo tailf /var/log/php5-fpm.log`

This gave me valuable feedback about a pool not being able to listen

2. `grep "\[www\]" *.conf`

This revealed that I had multiple .conf files that contained [www], I fixed this and restarted php5-fpm and nginx and the 502 errors disappeared and I was able to give the rogue site a pool name

Hope this helps someone